# How to create multi select attribute for customer using Microsoft SQL Server Management 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
   STUDENTID   INT              NOT NULL,
   STUDENTNAME VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
   STATE   VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,       
   ZIPCODE INT              NOT NULL,
   CONTACTNO INT              NOT NULL,
   DOB INT              NOT NULL,
   SEX VARCHAR (25)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTID)
);
```

I am not able to create multiple entry into the table for example phone contact no which user can have two different numbers. How to create multi select attribute in this table. What would be the best scripts for this:-

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store max of two numbers, you can create two columns in the table to store them like below

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
   STUDENTID   INT              NOT NULL,
   STUDENTNAME VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
   STATE   VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,       
   ZIPCODE INT              NOT NULL,
   CONTACTNO1 INT              NOT NULL,
   CONTACTNO2 INT              NOT NULL,
   DOB INT              NOT NULL,
   SEX VARCHAR (25)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (STUDENTID)
);
```